# Reading excel from DB (varbinary) in SSIS

Tags: ssis

First I'd like to say that I'm brand new to SSIS so bear with me if this is a very basic question. I've searched and cannot find an answer.

I need to read data from SQL Server that is stored in a varbinary column that contains an excel document. I then need to store this data into another table with the appropriate columns (pre-defined format).

My question is essentially... How do I read this varbinary data into something I can work with and then insert into another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Export Column Transformation` available within the Data Flow Task to read the varbinary data and then save it as a file on local disk where the SSIS package is running.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818.aspx) about Export Column transformation.

*Sample*: [The Export Column Transformation on BI Monkey](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/the-export-column-transformation/)

Using another data flow task, you can read the saved file and import the data into the table of your choice.

Comment: Is there a way to simply read the excel doc into memory without having to save it to disk? It's very basic document with 5 columns of data. I need to essentially insert each row from the excel doc into a DB table with the same columns as fields.